# Calendar does not refresh when deleting contacts

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

When I delete a contact, its birthday continues to stay on the default Calendar app, in the Birthdays calendar. (FYI, this calendar automatically gathers events from contacts' dates.)

How to update/refresh the Calendar in this case?

I went to the app settings and clicked on *Clear Cache*, with no result. Should I do a *Clear Data* too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do what I want via a combination of:

- removing the Birthday calendar from the web account
- removing the Birthday calendar from the calendar app
- doing a *Clear Cache* and *Clear Data* on the calendar app
- forcing a sync of my Google account on the phone